# When adding a pin with tap gesture, my pin shows up somewhere else..

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

As you can see everything works fine, but for some reason when I add the pin to the map, the latitude and longitude shows up in a different part.

Not sure what else to do, so this is my last resort..

this is just the snippet

here I'm initating the gesture recognizer

```
    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(gesturer:)))
    mapview?.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
```

adding annotation

```
func addAnnotationOnLocation(pointedCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let annotation2 = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation2.coordinate = pointedCoordinate
    annotation2.title = text.text
    mapview?.addAnnotation(annotation2)
    print("\(text.text)annotation")

}
```

and the work that gets done on the database and on the map to add the annoation

```
@objc func handleLongPress (gesturer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesturer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        print("began")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Activity", message: "Enter Below", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alertController.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
            textfield.placeholder = "activity here"
        }
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

            if let alertTextfield  = alertController.textFields?.first, alertTextfield.text != nil {
                //                    print("text here\(String(describing: alertTextfield.text))")
                //                    self.text = alertTextfield
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("text here\(String(describing: alertTextfield.text))")
                    self.text = alertTextfield
                    let touchPoint : CGPoint = gesturer.location(in: self.mapview)
                    let newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (self.mapview?.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapview))!
                    self.myPoints.append(newCoordinate)
                    print(newCoordinate.latitude, newCoordinate.longitude)
                    self.userpinning = newCoordinate
                    self.addAnnotationOnLocation(pointedCoordinate: newCoordinate)

                    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
                    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Map1").child(uid)
                    let values  = ["lat": self.userpinning.latitude, "long": self.userpinning.latitude, "Captio": self.text.text, "CreatingDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970] as [String: Any]
                    let mapref = ref.childByAutoId()
                    mapref.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                        print("err", err)
                    })
                }
            }
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: { (_) in
            alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: what do you see when you  log the points? how far off are the actual and intended pin locations?

Comment: it's like way off, for example the location i'm at is florida, and my points end up in Africa..

Comment: have you tried logging the CLCoordinate2D you are creating, and compare it with the  MKPointCoordinate values you are getting?. e.g., touch on NYC. What are the approx coordinates for NYC? And what is it actually setting as the coordinate inside the addAnnotationOnLocation function?

Comment: 58.28994105314928 -88.14709907758616 are the MKPointCoordinate I'm getting when the coordinates for NYC are 40.7128° N, 74.0060° W

Comment: where in the view controller lifecycle are you adding the gesture recognizer?

Comment: on view did load. this is how I'm adding it .          let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(gesturer:)))
    mapview?.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)

Comment: my only guess is that your views are not laid out until after viewdidload so it's  not getting the right touch point coordinates?. would it make any difference if you add it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: just tried. the views are appearing they just don't appear on the right coordinate. it's interesting as when I have  this out of the add function it adds it correctly..        let newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (self.mapview?.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapview))!
                        self.myPoints.append(newCoordinate)
                        print(newCoordinate.latitude, newCoordinate.longitude)
                        self.userpinning = newCoordinate
                        self.addAnnotationOnLocation(pointedCoordinate: newCoordinate)

Comment: to the right point on the map

Comment: Hard to understand the code in the comment. Can you update the question with this piece of code?

Comment: it's essentially the same piece of code that is after DispatchQueue.main.async in which it adds the pin. I had it outside of the .addAction and it shows correctly on the place I'm adding the pin, but I have to tap twice so it can show..

Comment: Sidenote: I use a Debouncer in the handler because this kind of code can fire dozens of calls per second in a real app.

Comment: try doing `let touchPoint : CGPoint = gesturer.location(in: self.mapview)` much earlier in your code, before calling `DispatchQueue`

Comment: Hey Gerd, how would you use a debouncer with this?